# Custom aggregate on Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a Telerik RadGrid to display 5 columns, out of which the relevant ones for this question are Total, OrderDate and DeliveryDate columns.

I want to SUM the Total under the Order Date and Delivery Date column footer respectively, based on two conditions:

> Order Date > Delivery Date

(when this condition is met, Total for such rows is displayed under Order Date), and

> Delivery date = Order Date

(when this condition is met, Total for such rows is displayed under Delivery Date.)

Looking for possible ways to do this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Telerik has good documentation. Please use https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/rows/summary-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the value of `Aggregate` property for the desired column(s) to `"Custom"` and following the approach from [Grid footer with multiple columns with custom aggregate](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-footer-with-multiple-columns-with-custom-aggregate#PM-oMZFXQ02ND1MinKLXNQ) forum thread, you will loop through the items and do the calculations.

Worh checking out the [Accessing Cells and Rows](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows) article to get a better understanding on how to access cells, controls, raw values in Grid items.